How to declare types for non-JS files centrally?
I am writing a bundler plugin (e.g. vite) that can load *.sql files directly in JS/TS. They will be transformed to valid JS modules during bundling.
Now I want to add type declarations for those files.
What I already tried
1. Wildcard declaration
Similar to most of other vite loaders, I can give *.sql files a general type:
declare module '*.sql' {
  const query: () => Promise<any>
  export default query
}

But this isn't what I need because different .sql file has different query result, therefore they should have different types.
import queryA from './a.sql'
import queryB from './b.sql'

const resultA = await queryA()
const resultB = await queryB()  // They should have different types

2. declare module with paths
I have also tried using declare module with a relative/absolute path of the file. This won't work for two reasons:

TS errors with "Ambient module declaration cannot specify relative module name".

Relative paths won't work anyways, because one .sql can be imported by different TS files with different relative paths.


3. Adding a something.sql.d.ts file next to the .sql file
This works in theory. But in my case types will be automatically generated by a code generator instead of written manually. Lots of, everywhere-scattered generated codes are very hard to manage.
So what I'm desiring is a centralized type declaration (at least in one folder) instead of this.

“Everywhere-scattered” declaration files are harder to manage than “everywhere-scattered” SQL files? Are you code splitting… or can you bundle the queries into a single module and also bundle the types in a single adjacent declaration file at the time of generation?

@jsejcksn As a plugin author, I have no right to decide or judge where my users put their .sql source files, but I'm obligated to provide a solution to ensure type-safety. If I have to do a code generation, I'm also responsible for not shitting everywhere.
